# How to get azcopy to work in docker

Tags: .net, docker, azcopy

my dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0.4-runtime

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         rsync \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN set -ex \
    && curl -L -o azcopy.tar.gz https://aka.ms/downloadazcopyprlinux \
    && tar -xf azcopy.tar.gz && rm -f azcopy.tar.gz \
    && ./install.sh && rm -f install.sh \
    && rm -rf azcopy
```

I am starting the container using dotnet client

```
    var container = await client.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(new CreateContainerParameters
    {
        Hostname = "",
        Domainname = "",
        User = "",
        AttachStdin = false,
        AttachStderr = true,
        AttachStdout = true,
        Tty = true,
        Volumes = ...
        Image = ...
        Cmd = arguments,            
        HostConfig = new HostConfig
        {
            LogConfig = new LogConfig { Type = "json-file" },
            AutoRemove = false,
            Binds = binds
        }

    });
```

equivilent to

```
docker run -v dataout:/data1/S2B_MSIL2A_20180107T102359_N0206_R065_T33UUB_20180107T121759.SAFE earthml/azcopy azcopy --source /data1/S2B_MSIL2A_20180107T102359_N0206_R065_T33UUB_20180107T121759.SAFE --destination https://eodata.blob.core.windows.net/test --dest-key  --recursive
```

but getting the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length
   at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.Interaction.WriteConsoleAtCursor(String message, Boolean finished)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.AzCopy.OutputNonVerboseTransferStatus(Nullable`1 transferredBytes, Boolean finished)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.AzCopy.ProgressUpdate(TransferStatus status)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferProgressTracker.InvokeProgressHandler()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferProgressTracker.AddProgress(TransferProgressTracker progressTracker)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferCollection`1.AddTransfer(Transfer transfer, Boolean updateProgress)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferManager.GetOrCreateDirectoryTransfer(TransferLocation sourceLocation, TransferLocation destLocation, TransferMethod transferMethod, TransferContext transferContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DataMovement.TransferManager.<UploadDirectoryInternalAsync>d__69.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.DirectoryTransferLauncher.<UploadDirectory>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.DirectoryTransferLauncher.<ExecuteImplAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.TransferLauncherBase.<ExecuteAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.BlobFileTransfer.DoTransfer()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.AzCopy.ExecuteTransfer()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.AzCopy.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.AzCopy.AzCopy.Main(String[] args)
/usr/bin/../lib/azcopy/azcopy: line 10:    15 Aborted                 dotnet $DIR/bin/azcopy.dll "$@"
```

### Update

I wanted to be clear, i use code to run the container, and the exception is thrown inside the container, in azcopy tool.

From the callstack we learned that azcopy is doing something with the console for progress reporting. Maybe thats not allowed in a docker container. Is there any way maybe to give the create/start container call some arguments that would allow  what it is doing.

### Update 2

I ran the command with the CLI which works. I tried both with -it and without. Both works. So i am back at dotnet docker client, what are the correct parameters to simulate what the CLI is doing.

```
PS C:\Users\pks> docker run -v E8A9547E29F57C223876982D46564150:/data1/S2B_MSIL2A_20180107T102359_N0206_R065_T33UUB_20180107T121759.SAFE earthml/azcopy azcopy --source /data1/S2B_MSIL2A_20180107T102359_N0206_R065_T33UUB_20180107T121759.SAFE --destination ht
tps://eodata.blob.core.windows.net/test --dest-key "" --recursive
[2018/01/31 21:53:59] Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total files transferred: 113
Transfer successfully:   113
Transfer skipped:        0
Transfer failed:         0
Elapsed time:            00.00:00:07
PS C:\Users\pks> docker run -it -v E8A9547E29F57C223876982D46564150:/data1/S2B_MSIL2A_20180107T102359_N0206_R065_T33UUB_20180107T121759.SAFE earthml/azcopy azcopy --source /data1/S2B_MSIL2A_20180107T102359_N0206_R065_T33UUB_20180107T121759.SAFE --destinatio
n https://eodata.blob.core.windows.net/test1 --dest-key "" --recursive
Finished 113 of total 113 file(s).
[2018/01/31 21:54:47] Transfer summary:
-----------------
Total files transferred: 113
Transfer successfully:   113
Transfer skipped:        0
Transfer failed:         0
Elapsed time:            00.00:00:06
PS C:\Users\pks>
```

Comment: I think the error isn't related to docker, It seems that you call substring method in your code and it throw this exception.

Comment: what is the value of `Hostname = "",
        Domainname = "",
        User = "",` did you use susbstring here?

Comment: The exception is not thrown in my code. its inside the docker container in azcopy tool made by microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Running with the following solved it

```
var container = await client.Containers.CreateContainerAsync(new CreateContainerParameters
{
    Hostname = "",
    Domainname = "",
    User = "",
    AttachStdin = false,
    AttachStderr = f,alse
    AttachStdout = false,
    Tty = false,
    Volumes = ...
    Image = ...
    Cmd = arguments,            
    HostConfig = new HostConfig
    {
        LogConfig = new LogConfig { Type = "json-file" },
        AutoRemove = false,
        Binds = binds
    }

});
```